# C3861: Identifier not found; method returning array c++

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-errors, return-type

I am trying to run my code but I'm getting errors at every location I call my two methods which return an array.

I have just started programming and have no clue about what's wrong in this.

I am posting the entire code below.

```
// Test.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int Log2(int n)
{
int m;
int ct = 0;
m = n;
while(m)
{
    m = m >> 1;
    ct++;
}
ct-=1;  //correction step

return ct;
}

int power(int n)
{
int x = 1;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) 
        x *= 2;

    return x;
}

void FFT(short int dir,long m,double *x,double *y)
{
int endoffile;
    long n,i,i1,j,k,i2,l,l1,l2;
    double c1,c2,tx,ty,t1,t2,u1,u2,z;

    n = 1;
n = power(m);

double xreal[16];// = new double[n];
double xcomplex[16];// = new double[n];

    i2 = n >> 1;
    j = 0;
    for (i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        if (i < j) {
            tx = x[i];
            ty = y[i];
            x[i] = x[j];
            y[i] = y[j];
            x[j] = tx;
            y[j] = ty;
    }
    k = i2;
    while (k <= j) {
        j -= k;
        k >>= 1;
    }
    j += k;
}

for(int k=0; k<n;k++)
{
double *find = getter(k, x, y, n);
xreal[k] = find[0];
xcomplex[k] = find[1];
}
if (dir=1)
{
for(int k=0; k<n; k++)
{
x[k] = xreal[k];
x[k]/=n;
y[k] = xcomplex[k];
y[k]/=n;
}
}
}

double* getter(int k, double *x,double *y, int n)
{
double realret = 0.0;
double imagret = 0.0;

for(int n2=0; n2<=n/2 - 1; n2++)
{
    double *a = complexgetter(n/2,n2,k);
    realret+=a[0] * x[2*n2]-a[1] * y[2 * n2];
    imagret+=a[1]*x[2*n2]+a[0]*y[2*n2];
}
double *mult= complexgetter(n,1,k);
for(int n4=0; n4<=n/4 - 1; n4++)
{
    double *a = complexgetter(n/4,n4,k);
    double tmpreal=a[0]*x[4*n4+1]-a[1]*y[4*n4+1];
    double tmpimag=a[1]*x[4*n4+1]+a[0]*y[4*n4+1];
    realret+=tmpreal*mult[0]-tmpimag*mult[1];
    imagret+=tmpreal*mult[1]+tmpimag*mult[0];
}
mult=complexgetter(n,3,k);
for(int n4=0; n4<=n/4 - 1; n4++)
{
    double *a = complexgetter(n/4,n4,k);
    double tmpreal=a[0]*x[4*n4+3]-a[1]*y[4*n4+3];
    double tmpimag=a[1]*x[4*n4+3]+a[0]*y[4*n4+3];
    realret+=tmpreal*mult[0]-tmpimag*mult[1];
    imagret+=tmpreal*mult[1]+tmpimag*mult[0];
}
double *ret = 0;// = new double[2];
ret[0]=realret;
ret[1]=imagret;
return ret;
}

double* complexgetter(int N, int i, int k)
{
double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;

double value = -2*PI;
value/=N;
value*=i;
value*=k;
double *ret = 0;
ret[0]=cos(value);
ret[1]=sin(value);
return ret;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
double x1[16] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
double y1[16] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
    //  double y1[16] = {0};
int m1 = 4;
int dir1 = 1;

FFT(dir1, m1, x1, y1);

    return 0;
}
```

The following are the errors I get.

```
test.cpp(67): error C3861: 'getter': identifier not found
test.cpp(90): error C3861: 'complexgetter': identifier not found
test.cpp(94): error C3861: 'complexgetter': identifier not found
test.cpp(97): error C3861: 'complexgetter': identifier not found
test.cpp(103): error C3861: 'complexgetter': identifier not found
test.cpp(106): error C3861: 'complexgetter': identifier not found
```

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are using `getter` and `complexGetter` before they are defined.  C / C++ essentially reads files from top to bottom.  So in the function `FFT` it sees a use of `getter` and has no idea what that is.  You need to add a declaration to tell C / C++ the shape of the method in order for it to be processed.

Put this above the `FFT` function

```
double* getter(int k, double *x,double *y, int n);
double* complexgetter(int N, int i, int k);
```

Notice the `;` at the end here.  This makes it a declaration.  Essentially a promise to the compiler that you will define a function with this shape later on

Answer (score 0):

There are no methods in that code, only functions.  Functions must be declared before using them.  If there is no recursion, that's simple - just define the function before the first use.